# Copy an array of LPTSTR

Tags: c++, memory-management, struct

I have a struct that represents an array of LPSTR and is defined as so:

```
struct MyStruct {
    DWORD cbString;
    LPTSTR * pbString;
}
```

I need to copy this struct to another identical struct.  My question is, how do I allocate the memory for the destination struct?  My first instinct would be:

```
destStruct.pbString = (LPTSTR*)malloc(totalSizeOfSrcStrings * sizeof(TCHAR))

for(int i = 0; i < srcStruct.cbString; i++) {
    destStruct.pbString[i] = (LPTSTR)malloc(_tcslen(srcStruct.pbString[i] * sizeof(TCHAR));
}
```

I'm not sure if the code in the for loop is necessary, though.

Comment: as far as I remember it should be `char*`, so sizeof(TCHAR) should be sizeof(CHAR)

Comment: Long pointer to string.  Defined (by Microsoft) as an array of 8 bit characters.

Comment: thats nice: `_tcslen(srcStruct.pbString[i] * sizeof(TCHAR))`, have you compiled this code?

Comment: I meant to type LPTSTR.  I've updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: Off-by-one bug, everybody forgets about the zero-terminator.  Use strlen(xxx) + 1.  You are using C++, do this the right way with a copy constructor and a destructor.

Comment: It actually depends on what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to make a deep or a shallow copy?

Comment: Deep copy I think.  I don't want any of the destination pointers pointing to the source pointer as it may be freed at some point.

Comment: @HansPassant I actually have that in my production code.  Got lazy and didn't type it here.

Comment: What made you decide to use `TCHAR`? Are you still supporting Windows 98? And why are you being lazy?! That laze just wastes our time. Don't post fake code. Don't waste our time. Paste the actual code so that we know that there are no errors in it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Habit mainly.  That and the fact that I'm using some CryptoAPI calls where some elements are defined as LPCTSTR while others are defined as LPTSTR and still others are defined as LPWSTR.

Comment: You are making your life way too hard. Use `wchar_t*` and compile for Unicode. And stop using C strings. Use `std::wstring`.

Comment: In this case, std::wstring ins't an option as the information that I'm working with is passed in from a c# app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, while you have no choice but to cast the result of `malloc` in C++, you still can avoid the useless practice of using typenames under `sizeof`. In your case the error in your first `malloc` is caused by exactly that: for some unexplainable reson you used `sizeof(TCHAR)` there, while the proper element size is actually `sizeof(LPTSTR)`.

Again, don't use typenames under `sizeof`. Your original `malloc` can be rewritten in a safer fashion as

```
destStruct.pbString = 
  (LPTSTR*) malloc(totalSizeOfSrcStrings * sizeof *destStruct.pbString);
```

The cycle might look as follows

```
for(int i = 0; i < srcStruct.cbString; i++)
  destStruct.pbString[i] = 
    (LPTSTR) malloc((_tcslen(srcStruct.pbString[i]) + 1) * sizeof *destStruct.pbString[i]);
```

P.S. Of course, a C-style cast in this case might also be a bad idea, but the code looks like something that might need to be cross-compilable.

Comment: So the first malloc should be srcStruct.cbString * sizeof(LPTSTR) and then use the for loop as written?

Comment: Am i daft? Doesn't sizeof(LPTSTR) simply return the size of a pointer instead of the size of the character type?

Comment: Ah yes he wants an array of LPTSTR... perfect

Answer (score 0):

As brightstar pointed out, it should be sizeof(CHAR), not sizeof(TCHAR)

LPTSTR = TCHAR*

LPSTR = CHAR*

Comment: Unfortunately for you the question contained a typo. Now that this has been fixed, your answer is wrong.